# Some alphabet cannot make it underline

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to draw the underline in this alphabet p, y, g, j. It cannot direct show the underline in this alphabet. Hope someone can guide me how to solve it.

Below is my coding:

```html
<td style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color:blue;">126-1 jjj</span></td>
```

The output is shown like below the picture:

[image: Output 1]

I want the expected result like below the picture:

[image: Output 2]

What I've tried the coding:

```html
<td style="display: inline-block; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><span style="color:blue;">126-1 jjj</span></td>
```

The output is shown me like below the picture, but the table format not same with original:

[image: Output 33]

Comment: That is specifically your font rendering engine trying its best to *make the text look nice.* In proper typography, characters extending below the baseline *aren't* necessarily underlined, as that simply looks crap.

Comment: Thanks @deceze comment. Can you provide example to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: My "solution" would be: *don't*. That's the proper typography for underlined "jjj". The user is going to be used to seeing it like that. There's little sense in bending over backwards to undo this specific typographic optimisation.

Comment: Ok. I try to find other method to replace it.

Comment: There is a reason for why the browsers do like that, you can see that in your "expected example", it is hard to read what it say. There are ways to do this easy but if you care about users you wont do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this satisfy your requirement.

```css
span {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-position: under;
}
```

```html
<td><span>126-1 jjj</span></td>
```

Comment: @SoonWinner glad to help.

Comment: FYI. It will not work in IE, Firefox for Android and Safari on iOS. See the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position#Browser_compatibility).